# Where I can get information from about lua's functionalities in lualatex?

Tags: luatex

Normally `_G table` / `_ENV table` query returns 38 entries in console BUT when we are on `lualatex` it returns (121 minus normal 38 minus my 3 functions below) = 80 additional entries. Some are self-explanatory, e.g. socket, unicode, version, etc. BUT others are not.

One of those 80 additional `types` is `tex` and I've used two out of a total of hundred functions, namely `print` and `sprint`, from it and I don't know the 
usage of the rest! Besides, `tex` has 17 more tables in it.

On my installation folder I've a `readme.en.html`, it's over 3k links of `pdf` documents and I think those are `package` oriented and it's practically impossible for anyone to go through all of those. AFAIK, LuaTeX doesn't have an IDE like Visual Studio, Qt, IntelliJ IDEA that lists all `types` along with relevant information to help us get better with it! Does it have detailed documentation on those 80 additional entries it loads with lualatex and functionalities of those functions/types for its end user?

To get those information, I've these 3 functions in a `.lua` file:

```
local x
-- lists contents of _G Table
function test1()
    x = 0
    for k, v in pairs(_G) do
        x = x + 1
        tex.print(string.format([[%d & $%s$ & %s \\]], x, k, v))
    end
end

-- lists functions of tex table 
function test2()
    x = 0
    for k, v in next, tex do
        if type(v) == 'function' then
            x = x + 1
            tex.print(string.format([[%d & $%s$ & %s \\]], x, k, v))
        end
    end
end

--lists types other than function of tex table
function test3()
    x = 0
    for k, v in pairs(tex) do
        if type(v) ~= "function" then
            x = x + 1
            tex.print(string.format([[%d & $%s$ & %s & %s \\]], x, k, v, type(v)))
        end
    end
end
```

and on my `tex` file, I've these:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\directlua{require("test")}

\begin{document}

\centering \_G-Table
\begin{longtable}{p{.1\textwidth} | p{.4\textwidth} | p{.5\textwidth}}
        \hline Sl. & Function / Table / etc. & Address \& Info \\ \hline
        \endhead \hline \endfoot \hline \endlastfoot
        \directlua{test1()}
\end{longtable}

\centering Functions in $tex$ Table
\begin{longtable}{p{.1\textwidth} | p{.4\textwidth} | p{.5\textwidth}}
        \hline Sl. & Function Name & Address \\ \hline
        \endhead \hline \endfoot \hline \endlastfoot
        \directlua{test2()}
\end{longtable}

\centering Non-Function types in $tex$ Table
\begin{longtable}{p{.1\textwidth} | p{.2\textwidth} | p{.4\textwidth} | p{.3\textwidth}}
        \hline Sl. & Name & Address & Type \\ \hline
        \endhead \hline \endfoot \hline \endlastfoot
        \directlua{test3()}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks a bit odd to combine a question about longtable with a question about lua functions. Better split this.

Comment: as we have said on your previous questions the preloaded lua tables are documented in the luatex manual (mostly)

Comment: `texdoc luatex` should open the manual

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes it does, got a 294 page document. Thanks.

Comment: you could also have found it on ctan, or the luatex project website. Not sure this question can really have an answer if the answer is simply "read the manual"  .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, reading is not bad BUT feeding is better. Unlike other `tex` engines `lualatex` has a robust library based on `lua`, it should provide us an smart IDE with intellisense to feed us information as we type on a `.lua` file! I don't know yet whether there are any extension in VS Code, Sublime Text, etc, that helps us with lualatex.

Comment: In VS I used Lua to write in qdex and I think that there was intellisense.

Comment: @manooooh, that's for plain lua. If I type `tex.`, nothing pops up!

Comment: none of the tex engines provide any editing environment at all. IDEs may be developed but that is a completely separate thing. You can use whatever editor you like. In any case asking about IDE is a completely different question to the question posted here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I wouldn't have asked this question and typed those 3 functions to list out if I had seen a list popping up after typing `tex.`.

Comment: but your question doesn't ask about an editing environment it asks about a manual, and if you were to ask about an editing environment you would need to ask about that editor not about luatex itself. An extension offering command completion for emacs isn't going to be very useful if you use texstudio or vscode or whatever.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, but you can give me such info, if any! as I'd mentioned in the 3rd para `AFAIK, LuaTeX doesn't have an IDE ...`

Comment: none of those ide are language specific so any of them could presumably have a setup for luatex but as i say that;s a question about that editor not a question about luatex. It isn't clear what answer you expect in _this question_ I don't see what answer can be given other than "the additional tables are documented in the manual"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I was satisfied with that in my first comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the additional pre-loaded tables are documented in the luatex manual (`texdoc luatex`) as are most of the functions contained in those tables. Sometimes some experimental functions appear in the source before they are documented, so iterating over through the Lua can show some surprises, but in general you will find documentation for all entries.

Comment: Why did I have to use `$%s$` here`([[%d & $%s$ & %s \\]], x, k, v))` in all those functions? `k` is a `string` type, but those functions don't work if use `%s` instead of `$%s$`! Which directory of `TexLive` should I use in VS Code to activate intellisense?